# office.js get currently selected body text in outlook

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I am developing an addin for the web version of outlook on mac and I am trying to get the currently selected body text of an email and access the right click context menu in the read pane. anyone know how to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in compose mode, you can get the currently selected body text of an e-mail by using:

`Office.context.mailbox.item.getSelectedDataAsync`

Kindly see documentation for this API here:
https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item?product=outlook&version=v1.5

If you are in read mode, there's currently no way to get the selected body text.
Kindly propose this as a feature request on UserVoice : https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

For the right-click context menu, there's no way to do that via the Outlook Web AddIns API. Kindly propose this as well via UserVoice.

Comment: Thanks for the info, very helpful! Unfortunately I would like to get this in read mode so I will propose the feature. Thanks again!

Comment: Any updates on this after 4 years? Can we get list of selected mail items and read their bodies in read mode in 2022?